# How do I partent an object to a bone in the blender hierarchy?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, import, parent-child, blender

So, I'm trying to make a simple RPG game using Blender and Unity.  I would like to have an empty object to be used as a weapon holding position parented to my right hand bone so that I can switch weapons in and out and they'll be able to animate along with my character by being the child of the empty position.  The problem I am having is that I can't get the empty position to be a child of the specific right hand bone, only the armature.  Is there a way to make this work?  Also, if this isn't a good procedure to accomplish what I am trying to do, please enlighten me with the proper way, I'm kind of a noob, thanks.

Comment: I believe you'll get a better answer over at the [GameDev StackExchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh man, my bad.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have assigned your bones correctly on your character, you should be able to add additional game objects into the joints of the character, ie. Swords, shields and other cool things.

Then you can use this code to quickly fetch specific defined bones:

```
_playerAnimator.GetBoneTransform(HumanBodyBones.LeftHand);
```

Which gets the bone transform.

Here is a quick snippet of the assigned bones using a PlayerAvatar on character.

[image]